# How to structure data inside Core Data for a two entity scenario

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I want these two entities:

```
Payment
 - name
 - date
 - value

Day
 - date
 - value
```

I want to use `Day` entity to save the total of `Payment's` at the end of the day to easier calculate week/month/year averages.

I don't see any relationship between these two. Do I have to use a context for each entity ? Or is there a easy way to just use Payment entity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't see any relationship between these two.

You should establish **one-to-many** relationship between day and payments.

[image]

You can add the relationship in `Relationships` section of Day entity. Don't forget to set the reverse relationship and `To Many` type.

[image]

Two approaches for Day's `average` property:

1. Store it in CoreData and update every time you add a new payment object ot this day. It will make sense if you need to read average value often.
2. You can define a computed property of Day entity and calculate it dynamically using all `payments` of that particular day. This may cause performance issues if you do it often, but you won't need to update the value every time a payment is inserted or deleted.

P.S. You say that you need to calculate average month/year as well. Just don't use Day's average for this purpose. I mean average of the days in a month is not the average of the payments in that month

> Do I have to use a context for each entity?

No, you don't. Your entities should live in the same context.

> Or is there a easy way to just use Payment entity ?

You could have done it without Day entity at all, just by implementing convenience class methods for `Payment` as below. Again, the downside is that you are doing all those fetch operations and calculations every time you need an average value, which is not the best solution if you need it often enough.

```
class func payments(from fromDate: NSDate, to toDate: NSDate) -> [Payment] {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date > %@ && date < %@", fromDate, toDate)
    //fetch and return payments with predicate
}

class func average(from fromDate: NSDate, to toDate: NSDate) -> Double {
    let payments = payments(from: fromDate, to: toDate)
    //calculate average of fetched payments
}
```